# CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

I know this is amateur stuff but I've been trying and trying to get this right and i can't seem to get a fix.

[image]

Please take a look at the website screenshot. I'm attempting to make the "call..." text to be inline and to the right of the best@flooring logo.

Here's the code HTML:

```
    <div class="level0">
    <div class="topbar">
        <h1><% title_content %></h1> <div class="facebookbutton"></div>
        <div class="phonetop">Customer services: <strong>0844 209 1560</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="header">
    <div class="level0">
    <div class="logonumber">
        <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="<% secure_url %>images/logo.png?r=1" alt="<% title_content %>" /></a>
    <div class="headernumber">
        <h2>Call  <br /> 01132 186 212 <br />for the best prices</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="headfloat">This contains all of the content located on the right hand side </div>
```

CSS

```
.level0{
width:970px;
margin:0px auto;
clear:both;
}
.topbar{
height:41px;
color:#747474;
/*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;*/
}
.header{
background:#fff;
height:166px;/*was 126*/
}

 .logonumber {
float:left;
display:inline-block;
 }

 .logo{
display:block;
 }

.headernumber{}
```

contains the nav, the card images, basket and search.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `float: left;` on both divs?

Comment: Float `.logo` to the left

Comment: i've tried floating the logo to the left but it doesn't work

Comment: It will work if there is room for the div to fit. If the combined width of the divs is larger than the container they wont

Comment: thanks guys, it works. It was because the container didn't allow enough room for all three divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
.headernumber {
    float: left;
}
```

and you also need to decrease the size of the `.headfloat` element because its width does not allow all three elements in the same line

so change the `.headfloat` rule to

```
.headfloat {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 13px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 350px; /*was 460px*/
}
```